# Как подключить свой JavaScript к чужому сайту?

Tags: javascript, браузер, faq

У меня нестандартная задача.
Вопрос:
Как подключить к сайту свой JavaScript ?

Т.е. к примеру, загрузился сайт в ВКонтакте, а в нем, кроме его скриптов, загружен еще мой , например кнопка нажимая на которую происходит клиент по не прочитанному сообщению.

Знаю, что в браузере возможно подключать CSS, но возможно ли это сделать для JavaScript  с последующим подключением Bootstrap ?

Если есть какие нибудь предложения и идеи буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Как подключить JavaScript или CSS без доступа к сайту?

подключаемся не стесняемся не проходм мимо добавляем свой любимый плагин в сравнительную таблицу

лично я, рекомендую `User JavaScript and CSS`

```
| имя                     | версия | браузер   | JS | CSS | имп | эксп | обл | ред | ру | - |
|-------------------------|--------|-----------|----|-----|-----|------|-----|-----|----|---|
| User JavaScript and CSS | 1.2.5  | C         | Y  | Y   | Y   | Y    | Y   | Y   | Y  | - |
| Tampermonkey            | 4.5    | С/F/S/E/O | Y  |     | /   | /    | -   | Y   | Y  | - |
| Stylish                 | 1.9.2  | C/F/S/O   |    | Y   | Y   | -    | Y   | -   | -  | - |
| -                       | -      | -         | -  | -   | -   | -    | -   | -   | -  | - |
| имя                     | версия | браузер   | JS | CSS | имп | эксп | обл | ред | ру | - |
```

---

```
| колонка | описание                      | - | сокращение | название браузера |
|---------|-------------------------------|---|------------|-------------------|
| версия  | рассмитриваемая здесь версия  | - | С          | Chrome            |
| браузер | C/F/S/E/O                     | - | F          | Firefox           |
| имя     | имя расширения                | - | S          | Safari            |
| JS      | JavaScript                    | - | E          | Microsoft Edge    |
| CSS     | CSS (не через JS а напрямую)  | - | O          | Opera Next        |
| имп     | импорт скрипта                | - | -          | -                 |
| эксп    | экспорт скрипта               | - | -          | -                 |
| обл     | храние на сервере / ?социалки | - | -          | -                 |
| ред     | редактор кода                 | - | -          | -                 |
| ру      | поддержка русского языка      | - | -          | -                 |
| -       | -                             | - | -          | -                 |

| ячейка | описание |
|--------|----------|
| Y      | да       |
|        | нет      |
| -      | не знаю  |
| /      | отчасти  |
| -      | -        |
```

## `User JavaScript and CSS` 1.2.5

Свои JavaScript и CSS на любом сайте.
Userscript и userstyle — расширение позволяет запускать собственные скрипты и стили оформления на любых сайтах. JavaScript и CSS подключаются мгновенно, еще до загрузки страницы, поэтому результат выходит без задержек.

Преимущества:

- Мгновенный запуск
- Возможность добавлять свои библиотеки
- Система URL масок позволяет гибко изменять список сайтов к которым будут применены изменения

[chrome.google.com/webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld)

В Н И М А Н И Е !!
НАСТРОЙКИ -> БИБЛИОТЕКИ

## `Tampermonkey` 4.5

Это бесплатное расширение браузера и самый популярный менеджер пользовательских скриптов для браузеров на базе Blink и WebKit, таких как Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Safari, Opera Next, и Firefox.
...
Кроме того, есть хорошие шансы на то, что несовместимые скрипты будут нормально работать при использовании Tampermonkey.

[сайт](http://tampermonkey.net/)

## `Stylish` 1.9.2

Стильный интернет со Stylish, пользовательским менеджером стилей. Устанавливайте темы и скины для многих сайтов и создавайте свои.
...
***Stylish предлагает темы и скины для сайтов и веб-аппликаций со всего мира, таких как***
✔ Поисковые машины – Google, Baidu, Yahoo
✔ Социальные сети - Facebook, Twitter, Reddit, Whatsapp, Instagram, WeChat
✔ Сайты для разработчиков – Stackoverflow, Github, JIRA, Thunderbird
✔ Браузеры – Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari
...
***Важная информация!***
Мы охраняем конфиденциальность ваших личных данных
...
нам необходимо собирать данные о вашей активности в интернете
...
Подробнее об этом – в нашей Политике конфиденциальности на странице: userstyles.org/login/policy.

Comment: а где это можно найти?

Comment: @Максим147, обратите внимание на раздел `настройки` -> `библиотеки`

Comment: посмотрите в сторону chrome/mozilla extesnion. Не так сложно написать свой, который будет инджектить стили скрипты в нужные вам урлы

Comment: @Nofate, точно также, как второй комментарий к этому ответу? хочу заметить, получивший 1 голос

Comment: @qwabra не вижу, что вам мешает улучшить ответ? У него 2 тревоги. Рано или поздно кто-то его исправит или удалит.

Comment: @qwabra все важное должно быть в ответах, а не в комментариях.

Comment: @Nofate удалять полезный ответ? Сверхразум.

Answer (score 2):

Расширение GreaseMonkey. Можно использовать чтобы писать js код для любой страницы.

Comment: Для Chrome Tampermonkey, он же работает и для других браузеров.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, зато `User JavaScript and CSS` на русском ) думаю стоит отредактировать ответ, и добавить туда `Tampermonkey` с уточнением кто для лиса кто для хрома

Comment: Ну и похоже в нем нельзя редактировать CSS (не через JS) что тоже обидно.

Answer (score 0):

**User JavaScript and CSS** - *Расширение для Chrome* - [Ссылка](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld)

Свои JavaScript и CSS на любом сайте
Userscript и userstyle — расширение позволяет запускать собственные скрипты и стили оформления на любых сайтах. JavaScript и CSS подключаются мгновенно, еще до загрузки страницы, поэтому результат выходит без задержек.

Преимущества:
- Мгновенный запуск
- Возможность добавлять свои библиотеки
- Система URL масок позволяет гибко изменять список сайтов к которым будут применены изменения

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]